# How do I enable Open In Browser?

Tags: web, browser, phpstorm

I think WebStorm can open a browser but I can not see how to do it. I do not see any browser icon in the toolbar:

[image: Can't see Browser popup in Editor]

I also do not see *Open in Browser* on my *View* menu:

[image: Can't see Open in Browser on View Task]

What do I have to do for these buttons to show?

Comment: do you have any custom plugins installed? Please provide your idea.log(https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files)

Answer (score 1):

> Make sure you have configured at least one Deployment configuration (File | Settings | Deployment --- "Local" should do just fine) and marked it as **default** for this project.
>
> Once properly configured you can right click on **file** in PhpStorm (Project View panel or Editor itself) and choose "**Open in Browser** ..." (the same via View | Open in Browser ...).
>
> If you have configured `browsers` in PhpStorm (File | Settings | Web Browsers) then you can also use "View | Web Preview ..." (or hold the mouse still for a second and choose appropriate browser icon in small semi-transparent popup/hint box in right top corner of the Editor window.

By [Andriy Bazanov from here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206371759-How-to-open-php-files-in-the-browser?page=1#community_comment_207008085).